# Windows 10 upgrade application does not launch

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade

I downloaded the Windows 10 update launcher from Microsoft that I did on several other machines, but for this one it will not start. I tried running all the updates and then a reboot. Still nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas that could cause or fix this? I ran an update repair tool as well. No error messages show.

EDIT:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade

This is where I am getting the file from.

EDIT: 
I did look for C:\Windows\panther\setuperr.log but that file does not exist.

Comment: Check the setup error logs (C:\Windows\panther\setuperr.log).  Run a disk check. Run an SFC /scannow, and then check CBS.log for errors, etc..

Comment: What application are you talking about specifically?  I have no idea what "Windows 10 update launcher" is exactly, provide filenames, that helps me do research.

Comment: I had this same issue - and I can't remember how I fixed it... I think there was a conflict with a KB update :S. However, can you explain why you want this? Is it to check compatability?

Comment: I was tasked with upgrading all the public machines to Windows 10 so my goal is to upgrade this machine to 10

Comment: The best way to upgrade to Windows 10, is to use the .ISO, an upgrade has never failed using that method.